# Arbitrary subset of quotient group or ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, notation, quotient-group

Let $R$ be a group/ring and $I$ a normal subgroup/ideal, and form the quotient group/ring $R/I$.
Is is legitimate to write either of the following?

$S/I$ is an arbitrary subset of $R/I$, where $S \subseteq R$.

$S/I$ is an arbitrary subset of $R/I$, where $I \subseteq S \subseteq R$.

If not, is there a way to represent an arbitrary subset (or subgroup or subring) of $R/I$ without just calling it $A$ or some other single variable? My question stems from wanting to find a way to represent a subset of the quotient ring before I actually check that it's an ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Some people like to use that notation, and some people hate it. I personally think the best way to go is to take your arbitrary subset $A \subseteq R/I$ and define $S = \pi^{-1}(A)$ where $\pi : R \to R/I$ is the canonical projection. Then $S/I$ is guaranteed to be $A$ and you don't have to worry about people disliking your notation.

Comment: This is helpful thank you! With regards to the two notations I suggested, is the second one valid in full generality, or do you lose possible subsets by restricting $S$ in this way?

Comment: It is not valid in full generality: if $I \subseteq S$, then $I/I \subseteq S/I$, i.e. $0 \in S/I$. This is not always the case -- indeed in full generality the subset of $R/I$ might be empty!

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about the possibility of it being empty. What about if we say $S$ is a subring, which will exclude that possibility? I don't think your argument would work, but I think the conclusion will still hold.

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is a subring of $R/I$ (or even just any additive subgroup), it will necessarily contain $0$, so we will have $I \subseteq \pi^{-1}(A)$.